# How to get back the "on demand" network waterfall in Google Chromes Developer Tools

Tags: networking, google-chrome, developer-tools

Chrome gave me a new version today; it's has one new feature I don't like. The network waterfall is not available unless you have the dev tools window open and reload. I like to be able to inspect a page and get the waterfall without having to reload the page. Any way I can get this back?

Chrome version is 9.0.597.94